# Saving a product programmatically errors on duplicate

Tags: product, database, command-line

I've created a command which saves a number of products using

```
// \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
$product->save()
```

or

```
// \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
$productRespository->save($product)
```

Is there a way of telling the magento 2 api to only save if the product doesn't exist? I have almost 500,000 products which I don't want to re-import each time.

Just checking this is the correct way to do it too - because its SUPER slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code below:

```
if (!$productRespository->get($product->getSku())) {
     $productRepository->save($product);
}
```

This code will check the product which has the SKU. Hope it help!